# How to check If there is no data for a specific field?

Tags: picklist

I have a Picklist & a pageblocktable which returns a series of row data like

I need to check If any record's SmartCategory field is not  matching the selected picklist value, it should be shown as unknown then get saved.

How to achieve this type of scenario?

Comment: Do you have a picklist that is bound to getSmartCategory() outside pageBlockTable, as well as picklists inside pageBlockTable? If this is correct how use will select different values? This is only possible if you have picklist outside pageBlock table and a textbox bound with smart_category__c field inside pageblock table.

Comment: inside it is a <apex:outputField value="{!investments.Smart_Category__c}"/> and outside selectedVal variable holds the value..

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem you have to bind onchange event on your SelectOptions element so that when user selects a value your page reload and display "Unknown" value in pageBlockTable. You can use Ajax if you want partial page refresh instead of full reload.

```
<apex:selectOptions value="{!selectedVal}"/>
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!SmartCategory}"/>
    <apex:actionSupport event="onselect" action="{!processSelection}" />                                                      
</apex:selectList>
```

Here `processSelection` method will be created in controller and it should match `selectedVal` with your record list and change value to UnKnown depending on logic you want to build. But this is slightly complex as you are returning records in `getAllInvestmentList()` method which always gets it from sandardardset controller's `getrecords()` method. Instead of getAllInvestmentList method directly returning record() you have to process records and change smart_category__c field before returning by checking value of `selectedVal()` property. After that you have to do same thing in `Adjusments()` method so that Unknown value is saved in database.

Comment: I want only in Adjusments() method it should check any null value for category and replace it with unknown..after this changes i can do the insert..like how to check which row has got null value..

Comment: You have to iterate on list returned by getAllInvestmentList() using a for(datatype variablename : list) loop and check value of variablename.fieldname equals null, if yes change it's value.